# How to customize the call to configure in override_dh_auto_configure for debuild?

Tags: debian, package, configure, dpkg

In my Debian package build, I have 3 packages: A, B, C to build with debuild. So far all the packages are called with the same configure pattern. How could I customize the call to .configure for all packages in debian/rules? For example,

A package: ./configure --prefix=/usr

B package: ./configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu

C package: ./configure --disable-test

Comment: if you found answer, please share it